# How to remove a specific constant string in Power Rename?

Tags: rename, powertoys

I have several files with names like
`The wonderful way to happiness () (My-StoredLibrary).azw3` and
`The best Paint to use on Canvas () (My-StoredLibrary).azw3`

Note the spaces and dashes I want to remove only the  `() (My-StoredLibrary)` string and can't figure out how to do it.

Can someone help?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add a short info about the operating system you are using.

Comment: Is "My-StoredLibrary" a constant string?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PowerRename
2. In the "Search for" field, enter  `() (My-StoredLibrary)` (with leading space)
3. Leave "Replace with" empty
4. Press Apply

[image]